# No diagnostic for pack expansion in std::index_sequence

Tags: c++, c++17

So I stumbled on this piece of code and I don't understand why the following
construct is not ill-formed.

```
template<typename T, std::size_t... lst> 
struct mystruct : std::index_sequence<lst..., sizeof...(lst)> { 
  T i; 
};

int main() {
  mystruct<int> obj;
}
```

This should be ill-formed since the instantiation of mystruct with T = int will yield the following class(after T is substituted with int):

```
template<int, std::size_t... lst> 
struct mystruct : std::index_sequence<, //Empty list expansion
                                      0> { 
  int i; 
};
```

How is the `std::index_sequence<, 0>` not ill-formed? This above compiles without an error.

Comment: Where does the Standard say that an empty parameter pack "should be ill-formed" in this context?

Comment: The comma in your "substituted" template list is wrong in a sense. I mean, the compiler doesn't do source-to-source translations for templates, so I'm not sure if the comma is why you think it's ill-formed, but either way it's not an issue.

Comment: This is a quite nice example of how templates are more than just text-replacement, and thinking of them as just being that quickly leads to wrong conclusions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An empty parameter pack is never "empty" in a way that would make a construct syntactically invalid.

> **[temp.variadic]**
>
> [7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.variadic#7) When N is zero, the instantiation of the expansion produces an
>   empty list. Such an instantiation does not alter the syntactic
>   interpretation of the enclosing construct, even in cases where
>   omitting the list entirely would otherwise be ill-formed or would
>   result in an ambiguity in the grammar. [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class... T> struct X : T... { };
> template<class... T> void f(T... values) {
>   X<T...> x(values...);
> }
>
> template void f<>();    // OK: X<> has no base classes
>                         // x is a variable of type X<> that is value-initialized
> ```
>
> — end example ]

So it's not `std::index_sequence<, 0>`, but rather `std::index_sequence<0>`.

Answer (score 3):

It is not illformed since it expands to `std::index_sequence<0>`. The parameter pack expansion works not just on a textual level but it also works with the intent of what is done. Otherwise, working with potentially empty parameter packs would be a real mess.